# Using C# abstract class property for Xml serialize

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I want to create an generic abstract type as base for my xml serialized types:

```
public abstract class RootElementBase<TEelment>
{
    public IList<TElement> SubElements {get;set;}

    public RootElementBase(){ 
         SubElements = new List<T>(); 
    }
}
```

And I will use like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "myroot")]
public class MyRoot: RootElementBase<ItemType> {
     [XmlElement("item")] 
     public override List<ItemType> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

But this does not serialize MyRoot class. Implemented types use generic abstract class for Elements type. But XmlElelemt attribute tags will be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization and deserialization of derived types is supported. The following attributes control the Xml Serialization:

- `[XmlElement]`
- `[XmlAttribute]`
- `[XmlIgnore]`

We need to instruct the Xml serializer to ignore the base class members that we wish to work with in our concrete derived types.

See -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/attributes-that-control-xml-serialization

Also, be-careful with virtual member calls in the constructor
See -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx

Give this a shot:

### Solution 1

Using the derived class  **MyRoot** as the *type* parameter for the **XmlSerializer**

Abstract base class:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class RootElementBase<TEelment>
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual List<TEelment> SubElements { get; set; }

    protected RootElementBase()
    {
        SubElements = new List<TEelment>();
    }
}
```

Concrete Class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "myroot")]
public class MyRoot : RootElementBase<ItemType>
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public override List<ItemType> SubElements { get; set; }
}
```

Dummy ItemType Class:

```
public class ItemType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This will output the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myroot xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <item>
    <Name>Jim</Name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <Name>Ben</Name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <Name>Tom</Name>
  </item>
</myroot>
```

Test Console App:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyRoot root = new MyRoot();
        root.SubElements.Add(new ItemType() { Name = "Jim"});
        root.SubElements.Add(new ItemType() { Name = "Ben" });
        root.SubElements.Add(new ItemType() { Name = "Tom" });

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRoot));
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, root);

        Console.WriteLine(stringWriter);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

### Solution 2

Using the abstract base class *RootElementBase* as the *type* parameter for the **XmlSerializer** with an `XmlRoot` override parameter

Per MSDN:

> The root element of an XML document encloses all the other elements.
>   By default, the object specified by the type parameter is serialized
>   as the root element. Properties, such as the XML element name of the
>   root element are taken from the type object. However, the root
>   parameter allows you to replace the default object's information by
>   specifying an XmlRootAttribute; the object allows you to set a
>   different namespace, element name, and so on.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65k4wece(v=vs.110).aspx

Abstract Base Class:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(MyRoot))]
public abstract class RootElementBase<TEelment>
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual List<TEelment> SubElements { get; set; }

    protected RootElementBase()
    {
        SubElements = new List<TEelment>();
    }
}
```

Concrete Class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "myroot")]
public class MyRoot : RootElementBase<ItemType>
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public override List<ItemType> SubElements { get; set; }
}
```

Dummy ItemType Class:

```
public class ItemType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Sample Console App with Generic Serialization

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyRoot root = new MyRoot();
        root.SubElements.Add(new ItemType() { Name = "Jim"});
        root.SubElements.Add(new ItemType() { Name = "Ben" });
        root.SubElements.Add(new ItemType() { Name = "Tom" });

        string xml = Serialize(root, "myNewRoot");

        Console.WriteLine(xml);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static string Serialize<TElement>(RootElementBase<TElement> tElement, string rootElementName)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootElementBase<TElement>),
            new XmlRootAttribute(rootElementName));

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, tElement);

        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Note - With This solution** you need to be aware of Dynamically Generated Assemblies

**Dynamically Generated Assemblies**
To increase performance, the XML serialization infrastructure dynamically generates assemblies to serialize and deserialize specified types. The infrastructure finds and reuses those assemblies. This behavior occurs only when using the following constructors:

```
XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(Type)

XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(Type, String)
```

If you use any of the other constructors, multiple versions of the same assembly are generated and never unloaded, which results in a memory leak and poor performance. The easiest solution is to use one of the previously mentioned two constructors. Otherwise, you must cache the assemblies in a **Hashtable**, as shown in the following example.

Please see MSDN for Remarks: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you provide the error / stack trace and sample code? I am able to run the code above without issue.

Comment: @barteloma I've added a sample console application to my solution. Please see above.

Comment: @barteloma I've added a second alternative solution that uses the abstract base class RootElementBase as the type parameter for the XmlSerializer with an XmlRoot override parameter. See solution #2 above.